# Cannot edit my Stack Overflow Careers profile?

Tags: support, jobs

I have an account on Stack Overflow and I also have a Stack Overflow Careers profile.

My problem is that I cannot edit my careers profile.

I cannot add new answers.

I want to change from passive to active candidate, but I cannot.

What do I do?

Comment: We need more details. What happens when you try to edit? Do you get errors? If not, what you mean by "can't edit" exactly? To get help, you must provide more details.

Comment: @ShadowWizard When I click on add to add an answer,nothing happens.

Comment: @ShadowWizard When I click on looling for a job radio button, nothing it prints in red the word error below the radio button.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The things that I can edit, allow me to edit but hitting the save button does nothing.

Comment: Sounds like client side errors. What browser you have? What OS? Please edit your question with those details, if you see error in the browser's Console also paste it.

Comment: @Dante I kinda suspect a client side issue... Use a different browser and try edit, see what happens.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you very much,changing the browser did work.

Comment: @Dante just  curious, what browser was it? Please share, so that others with same problems will know not to use it for Careers. (and who knows, maybe the team will adjust the site at some point to support it)

Comment: Also, you can do that as a self-answer, otherwise I'll write one myself so that the solution won't be buried down in comments only.

Comment: @ShadowWizard go ahead.

Comment: OK, but still better know what browser... unless you prefer to keep it for yourself for some reason, which is also fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Careers site is using some JavaScript to perform certain actions.

Since JavaScript is client side, it might not work in some browsers, and thus break some actions.

Before using Careers, make sure to go over [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) and see your browser is supported and that you have everything that is needed.